# Restore contents of deleted user

Tags: posts, pages, database

I want to know if there is a way to restore contents of permanently deleted users from my WordPress page.

Comment: Before you delete the user you are asked if you want to assing the contents to another user or if you want to delete the associated content as well with the user. If you don't have a backup to restore from, you have nothing to do, permanent means permanent.

Comment: Thank you, there was not my website, I know how to delete users without deleting the files, but a friend ask me for help and i was trying to find if there was a solution for his fatal error.

Answer (score 4):

None that don't involve a backup. If you have a backup, you'll have to do some work to restore only a certain user's data without resetting everything to that point. I'd say import the backup into an empty database, then copy data over either with SQL (`INSERT INTO wp_posts SELECT FROM otherdb.wp_posts WHERE post_author = ...`) or with a script (getting the usermeta, posts and postmeta data).

If you don't have a backup, you might get somewhat lucky with caches (Google, Internet Archive), but recovering content from that will be more labor intensive and you will likely not get all the content.

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me, i was devastated as it was time to hand over the site the actual owners.

The good news is that i recovered all my data, but lost all the users.

Steps to follow (PAGES)

1. go to Pages in the admin panel and click on it
2. look at the top pane where there is (All) (Published) (drafts) (bin)
3. click on bin > select all the pages and restore all of them.( you will see restore at the drop down menu where you have delete)

Steps to follow (POSTS)
1. go to Posts page in the admin panel and click on it.
2. look at the top pane where there is (All) (Published) (drafts) (bin)
3. click on bin > select all the posts and restore all of them.( you will see restore at the drop down menu where you have delete)

not go to Settings on the Admin Panel left sidebar

Settings > reading > Select Homepage and Posts page. then click save. Kudos! you are good to go

Comment: This is a great answer!